# Как отправить cookie через POST-запрос Flutter

Tags: django, ajax, flutter, dart

Нужно сделать авторизацию с приложения на flutter, на сервере есть api страница, которая должна принимать sessionid и csrftoken, тем не менее выдает ошибку:

**You are seeing this message because this site requires a CSRF cookie when submitting forms.**

CSRF Token вытаскиваю следующим способом:

```
getCsrfToken() async {
      dynamic getResponse = await Requests.get("url", json: true); 
      String responseHeaders = getResponse.headers['set-cookie'];
      var fin =  responseHeaders.split(';');
      var fin2 = fin[0].split('=');
      final csrftoken = fin2[1];
      print('generated csrf: $csrftoken');
      return csrftoken;
    }
```

Затем использую для получения sessionid, передавая на сервер логин, пароль, а так же вызываю метод получения csrf token. Работает, возвращает sessionid

```
ajaxGetSessionId() async {

    var csrftoken = await getCsrfToken();
    
    print('csrf used for gettin sessionid: $csrftoken');
     dynamic response = await Requests.post("url/api_url", headers: {"Referer": "url"}, body: {"username":"username", "password":"password", 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken}); 
     final sessionId = (((response.headers['set-cookie'].split(';'))[4].split(','))[1].split('='))[1];
     print('generated sessionid: $sessionId');

     return sessionId;
}
```

Затем пытаюсь получить данные с другой api страницы, но получаю вышесказанную ошибку

```
ajaxGetAlbums() async {
      
      var sessionId = await ajaxGetSessionId();
      var csrftoken = await getCsrfToken();

      print('used csrf: $csrftoken');

      dynamic getAlbums = await Requests.post("url/api_get_data", headers: {"Referer": "url", 'Cookie': sessionId}, body: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken});
      print('recieved sessionid: $sessionId');
      print(getAlbums.content());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуй

```
body: json.encode({'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken})
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]